# Integer values of $a$ in quadratic equation

Tags: algebra-precalculus

> How many integer values of $a$ for which $x^2+ax-5005=0$ has integer roots.

what i try

Let Roots be $\alpha,\beta.$ Then $\alpha+\beta = -a$ and $\alpha \beta =-5005$

$\Rightarrow \alpha \beta = -5\cdot 7 \cdot 11 \cdot 13$

How do i solve it Help me please

Comment: Do you know how to find the number of prime factors from the factorisation? What's stopping you from finishing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use condition for integral roots.$$ $$
Coefficient of $x^2$ be integer and D be perfect square of an integer.
i.e $$ D=a^2+4(5005)=m^2 \,,\,m\in I $$
Now follow as in the link https://www.mathsdiscussion.com/forum/topic/quadratic-integral-roots/?part=1#postid-74. $$ $$
In you case there will be 16 different values of a like $$ \pm5004,\pm996,\pm708,\pm444,\pm372,\pm128,\pm36,\pm24$$